# Elastic Search - Pagination on Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index and I query an aggregation, instead of returning the whole aggregation at once I want to have it returned in chunks, that is small small blocks, is it possible to do so in Elastic Search?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754116/elasticsearch-paginating-a-sorted-aggregated-result/54800209#54800209 (hint: use `composite` agg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Bucket sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html)

```
POST /sales/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "sales_per_month" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "total_sales": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                },
                "sales_bucket_sort": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                          {"total_sales": {"order": "desc"}}
                        ],
                        "size": 3,
                        "from": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That ok if I want to get the top 3 records but what if I want the top 4th, 5th and 6th record and then the next 3 in other blocks. what I want to do is to receive this data in a block of 3 or some size and process this data via threads in java.

Comment: @RaviJain there is properties from and size

Comment: @RaviJain maybe i misunderstood you but i thought you want to load them in multiple requests. thats the only way

Comment: Yeah I checked it out but it looks like it works only for hits, and not for aggregations, please correct me if I am wrong on that, I am really new to elastic search.

Comment: @RaviJain check my sample one more time, its for aggregation where you can do "paging" for aggregation. You can also do size, from for hits but thats different.

Comment: You see i have a lot of user data, i want to group this data by user_id and then the there are further aggregations on this data but i want the data grouped by user_id not come as whole block as that would be too large so i want to get it in small chunks so that i can process it in easily via threads.

Comment: What is stopping you to take in first request first 100 aggs then next 100 and so on? there is no way to get in chunks in one request ES is not streaming. You must do different trip

Comment: i got your point, let me try to run this and check if it solves my problem. thank you so much for the prompt reply. you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: on the aggregation above bucket_sort i have user_id (string value) is it possible to do so on strings as it shows me an error.