# Elasticsearch Paginate Aggregation

Tags: php, elasticsearch, pagination

Is there a way in elasticsearch to paginate aggregation results?
I tried 'partition' and 'num_partitions' without success.

```
'session': {
 'terms': {
  'field': 'data.session.keyword', 
  'size': 100, 
  'include': {'partition':1, "num_partitions":10},
  'order': sortQuery
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire query here please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389601/elastic-search-pagination-on-aggregations could be helpful