# Group by and pagination in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I group by and paginate documents in ElasticSearch? It seems like aggregation in ElasticSearch doesn't support pagination, is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Here you go, this is probably the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800209/4604579 (hint: composite aggregation)

Comment: it says _if you want to know how many buckets in total there is going to be, the composite aggregation won't give you that number._

Comment: That wasn't explicitly expressed in your question that you wanted to know how many buckets there were, only that you wanted to paginate over terms buckets